# Type.GetTypeFromCLSID and Type.GetTypeFromProgID get cached result?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, com, interop

My program uses COM drivers from 3rd party.
I am trying to implement switching between different driver versions.

First I tried using Interop dlls generated by VS and calling regsvr32 from code. I was able to make calls to drivers via Assembly.Load and reflection, but it seemed that despite the fact that I was calling different Interop libraries I was getting the same version. I tried registering and unregistering libraries via regsvr32 before calling interops and tried making a delay in case regsvr32 works slowly.

In the end I removed interop libraries and decided to work directly with COM.
Both versions of drivers have the same CLSID. I ended up with code that just tries to instantiate a COM object and get a property that gets a version value.

```
while (true)
        {
            var CLSID = new Guid("E4795281-3564-11D4-8E97-0080C87C930A");
            var type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID);
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            object propertyValue = type.InvokeMember("Version", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, obj, null);
            Console.WriteLine(propertyValue);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

I run the program and then try to manually register dlls. No matter how long I wait after registration my program instantiates the version it got at the beginning. If I restart the programm - it gets the last registered version. I see that registry record changes, so I think that there might be some caching issue.

I tried running code in separate AppDomain and recreating it, but it didn't help.

I also tried using `Type.GetTypeFromProgID` with the same result.

Any suggestions for workaround?

Comment: Do you need to deregister the first before loading the second ? Can you PInvoke and create two different signatures to the two DLL's ?

Comment: @OrdinaryOrange I tried deregistering but it didn't make any difference. I don't think it is neccessary, since registering overrides previous records from what I can see in registry.
I didn't try using PInvoke, since if I understand correctly that would require me to write down layout for both versions of dll. Any material you can recommend to read about using PInvoke? From what I understand it doesn't have anything to do with COM, right? It's just another way to call unmanaged things

Comment: Yeah, Pinvoke is direct call to the methods direct. Yes you are right you would need another layer.  It can be painful to configure the managed signatures and was just a left field idea. I wonder if SxS might hep I'll post some details.

Answer (score 0):

Try Reg Free COM, I recall reading somewhere it is good for dealing with multiple versions and avoiding the conflicts.

I'm assuming you are usign VS. Go back to just normal Interop. Add the COM references to you project to automatically generate the interop interfaces. Then right click the interop reference and set Isolated=True. Make sure you have the COM registered in the registry at this point.
Now compile your program. You should see a .manifest file generated in the output folder along with the .exe. Open the manifest in notepad and hopefully it has both dll's listed with all the various CLSID's and TLIB's.
Unregister all the COMs from the registry (with Regsvr32).

Now run the application. 
In this mode the activation context will query the .manifest for all the necessary resources rather than the registry, and hopefully it should then allow the calls to each dll version correctly.